# Parsing json into a list of values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a program that takes some file and transforms it into a json format.

Im trying to get all the values of certain keys into a list but, because the format of the json file has a bunch of keys that are present multiple times, I cant find a way to do it properly.

My json file looks like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "__schema": {
            "queryType": {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "project"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectEventFeed"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectEventFeedFetchMore"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectRecentEventFeed"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "unseenProjectActivityCount"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectFiles"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectFilesIdSet"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectFileMessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectUserStatus"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "projectFileScribble"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "user"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "viewer"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "profile"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "site"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "designers"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "predictImageCategory"
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "getPortfolioDesign"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to get all the name values into a list.

Before turning the file into json, I tried getting that with regex but failed.
With json format I tried the following

`map(lambda parsed_json: parsed_json['data']['__schema']['queryType']['fields']['name'], List)`

Im getting `List` from `typing`

But when i want to turn the map into a list, I get

`TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got 0.`

From the conversion.

Comment: Im getting `List` from `typing`.

Im doing `from typing import List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use list comprehension on the nested `'fields'` key in the dict you have converted from your json.

```
d = {"data": {"__schema": {"queryType": {"fields": [{"description": "", "name": "project"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectEventFeed"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectEventFeedFetchMore"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectRecentEventFeed"}, {"description": "", "name": "unseenProjectActivityCount"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectFiles"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectFilesIdSet"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectFileMessages"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectUserStatus"}, {"description": "", "name": "projectFileScribble"}, {"description": "", "name": "user"}, {"description": "", "name": "viewer"}, {"description": "", "name": "profile"}, {"description": "", "name": "site"}, {"description": "", "name": "designers"}, {"description": "", "name": "predictImageCategory"}, {"description": "", "name": "getPortfolioDesign"}]}}}}

fields = [f['name'] for f in d['data']['__schema']['queryType']['fields']]
print(fields)
# ['project', 'projectEventFeed', 'projectEventFeedFetchMore', 'projectRecentEventFeed', 'unseenProjectActivityCount', 'projectFiles', 'projectFilesIdSet', 'projectFileMessages', 'projectUserStatus', 'projectFileScribble', 'user', 'viewer', 'profile', 'site', 'designers', 'predictImageCategory', 'getPortfolioDesign']
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I was trying to do something similar but failed at it